# Is there a way to apply LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. for every command automatically?

Tags: shared-library

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. ./myAppUsingAlibraryInThisDirectory
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:. ~/dir/anotherAppUsingLibraryFromHere
```

Is there a shortcut for this so that I don't need to re-prefix with same command for every command?

Windows doesn't need anything like this but I prefer to use Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do something like

```bsh
SOME_VARIABLE=some_value some_command
```

you run `some_command`, but with an environment variable `SOME_VARIABLE` set to `some_value` for only this single command.

When you write the assignment on a separate line, without any following command, the variable will be set to this value for the entire shell session, i.e. normally until you close your terminal. You will most likely have to `export` the variable, so that it is not only available within the shell but also to all of its subshells and child processes, i.e. the commands you will run:

```bsh
export SOME_VARIABLE=some_value

some_command
another_command and so on
```

This way the variable lasts for your whole shell session, but it won't persist across sessions. It will be gone when you open a new terminal. To persist variables for all your shell sessions, you have to set them within your shell startup scripts, usually `~/.profile`. Simply append the line that exports your variable to the end of this file and all your shells that you open from then on will have it set.

Another note for your specific case of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:.` though: You should avoid specifying relative paths (here `.` referencing your current working directory) in any path-related environment variables. These relative paths will always be resolved *relative to your current working directory whenever you run a command that uses it*, not relative to your working directory at the moment when you define the variable. This can have unintended and confusing side effects and even be security threats. Always use absolute paths.